# Extending a CRTP template functionality

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm a bit new to templates so bear with me if I'm asking obvious questions.

Given the following class hierarchy:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton_T
{
  ...
  static T& getInstance(){ ... }
  ...
}


template<typename T>
class Pool_T: public Singleton_T<Pool_T<T> > 
{
  ...
  T* createObject();
  ...
}
```

Now I want a class that extends the `Pool_T` functionality while also being a `Singleton_T`.

So I want to have in the new class the methods`getInstance` defined in Singleton_T and `createObject` defined in `Pool_T` tailored to my new type.

The initial approach would be:

```
struct myStruct;
class Manager : public Pool_T<myStruct>
{
  ...
  void loadObjectsFromFile();
  ...
}
```

However , this makes the `GetInstance` of the `Singleton_T` to instantiate and return `Pool_T<myStruct>` type, so the `loadObjectsFromFile` method won't be available via `getInstance` (an object of Manager type won't be created).

In order to solve this I made the following change in hierarchy :

```
template< typename TDerrived, typename T>
class Pool_T : public Singleton_T < TDerrived >
{
  ...
  T* createObject();
  ...
}

class Manager : public Pool_T<Manager, myStruct>
{
  ...
  loadObjectsFromFile();
  ...
}
```

Now I can use all the three methods: `getInstance`, `createObject` and `loadObjectsFromFile`.

However this forces `Pool_T` to no longer be possible to instantiate from only 1 type.

EG:

```
struct someStruct;
class StructPool : public Pool_T<someStruct>; // no longer possible
```

In order to "solve" this i defined another template:

```
template <typename T>
class AlonePool_T: public Pool_T<AlonePool_T<T>, T>
{
   // empty class
   // allows instantiation of what was previously Pool_T<someStruct>
}
```

Now I can use this where previously `Pool_T<someStruct>` was defined.

```
 struct someStruct;
 class StructPool : public AlonePool_T<someStruct>;
```

However this will result in allot of find and replace in code that I'm not owner off.

Is there any way to achieve the following:

- maintain Pool_T original definition
- create a class that extends the Pool_T functionality (adds the `loadObjectsFromFile` method)
- the class has `getInstance` and `createObject` methods correctly implemented (the correct types are used)

**EDIT:**

Added three methods to better underline the desired effect.
Given's liliscent's answer I changed the hierarchy to better show what I'm after.

Comment: Why your `Pool_T<T>` inherit `Singleton_T<T>` ? Obviously a `Pool_T<T>` instance is *not* a singleton of T.

Comment: Since real class bodies are replaced with `{ ... }`, it is not very clear what the actual problem or error is.

Comment: @liliscent good catch, modified the question.

Comment: The solution will depend on what derived class each class implementation actually needs to know about, or not.  Is `GetInstance()` supposed to return a type based on the absolutely most derived type, or something in between?  In your second example, it looks like it would return `Manager_T<myStruct>`, even though the most derived type `Manager` has some additional members.

Comment: @aschepler Oh, you are right. I will modify the code in order to provide the correct behaviour. I want the class to return the "most derived type" with specific implementation. I guess moving the implementation inside the template will be sufficient for what I need.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't copy pasted the implementation here since it's huge and I find it irrelevant. I need GetInstance from Singleton<T> to return a type that extends Pool_T functionality.

Comment: (Off topic, but: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1270/6432)

Comment: @aschepler :) :) . Good to know. I guess I've been inviting quite a few individuals to undress in my emails as well :) .

Comment: Post just the relevant parts, and all the relevant parts. If you want help with fixing `GetInstance`, then`GetInstance` is relevant, don't omit it.

Comment: Do you want a pool of T to also be a singleton of T? It isn't quite clear why or how as these things usually provide incompatible functionality. It would be rather confusing. However if you so inclined, it is entirely possible for a `Pool<T>` to inherit both `Singleton<T>` and `Singleton<Pool<T>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, a typical CRTP implementation of your hierarchy is:

```
template<class T>
struct Singleton {};

template<class Derived, class T>
struct Pool
    : public Singleton<Derived>
{};

struct MyStruct {};

struct Manager 
    : public Pool<Manager, MyStruct>
{};
```

Comment: Correct. That's a much better way of writing the hierarchy ( I can actually have the most derived class). But this changes the `Pool_T` definition.

Comment: You want to keep your `Pool` as a `template<class T> struct Pool` ? Then I think you can decouple the `Singleton` restriction and the `Pool`, and let the most-derived class inherit directly from `Singleton`.

Comment: Well decoupling is a method among others, however I want to know if it's possible with mantaining the same 'template<class T> class Pool' definition as well in some form or way. Same= still singleton.